# Locating the next occurence of a character ===> (found Unit required Boolean, error)

Tags: string, scala, char, boolean

I know this question has been asked plenty of times, but I keep getting:found Unit required Boolean error. I tried looking at various solutions and implementing them (at SO) but none of them works.

Thanks for help !! xx

P.S My function is part of a bigger program in which the general idea is that we've got a buffer(which contains a given string) and we find the occurrences of character inside the buffer. What's also needed if we find the occurrence the function has to return at what number(in this case cursor) the occurrence has appeared and also return a Boolean statement (true ==found an occurrence) else(false == did not find an occurrence).

```
class buffer(s:String){

private var buffer: StringBuilder = new StringBuilder(s) 
private var cursor: Int = 0

//function which checks the occurrence of a given string inside the "buffer"
def ff(c: Char): Boolean = {

    var  getWord = ""

    var Solution = 0

    //get String method is used to see if buffer is not empty
    if(getString != ""){

      for(x <- cursor until buffer.length by 1){
        if(buffer.charAt(x)==c)
        {
           Solution = x

          return   true;
        }   

         else
     return false }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `s.find(c).isDefined`

Comment: `s.indexOf(c)` returns the index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want a bit more than you really ask. But if you just want to check if a Character exists in a String, all you need to do is:

```
s.exists(c == _)
```

Here your whole example:

```
val s = "asdfasdfERerfasdfasfasdfdsfdfa-asdfasdfafg"

def ff(c: Char): Boolean = s.exists(c == _)

println(ff('e')) // -> true
println(ff('x')) // -> false
```

Let me know if this solves already your problem - or if you have additional requirements.

Comment: I always make it too complex from myself. This solves my problem. Thanks very  much for the answer

Comment: yeah - if it is not done in one line in Scala - there might be a better solution;)